# localizar una función del tema andros

Tags: wordpress-theme

Estoy trabajando con un tema hijo de andros y quiero cambiar la función andros_base_footer() para añadirle un texto fijo (además del que el usuario ponga mediante su panel de administración). El problema es que no localizo dónde se define la función, sólo cuando la llama.
¿Alguien tiene idea de por dónde o cómo buscar? ya he buscado en el footer.php en function.php en la carpeta base y nada.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La anulación o sobreescritura de funciones de un tema padre es más complicado que anular archivos de plantilla o estilo, pero se puede hacer. Hah tres métodos para conseguirlo:

- 1.Si estás escribiendo tu propio tema padre, utiliza funciones conectables de manera que una función en el tema hijo con el mismo nombre lo reemplace.
- 2.Asigna mayor prioridad a las funciones tu tema hijo para asegurarte de que se ejecuten despues de las del tema padre y pueda funcionar tal como esperas.
- 3.Usa remove_action()o remove_filter()para quitar funciones en el tema padre por completo.

El método que utilices dependerá de la forma en que el tema padre esté codificado y si es necesario  eliminar la función por completo de los temas padres, o simplemente ejecutar otra función después que anule la primera.

Y como otra opción, ¿Has pensado a utilizar un [SHORTCODE](http://programandoamimanera.com/shortcodes-en-wordpress-uso-y-utilidad/) en el archivo footer.php de tu tema hijo?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo intentaré